# Does SFMC Push Message support Amscript RaiseError Function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobilepush

thank you for your time.

I wonder if Amscript RaiseError Function works for push message? I tried a few test and it's not working on my end, however I couldn't find any evidence that confirm or deny this information officially?

If RaiseError is not working for push, are there any way to stop the send similar to Email's Exclusion Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you sent the Push message but here is what I tried:

Context:

PN message is created from Content Builder
PN message is sent from Journey Builder

PN message content:

```
%%[
    if 1 == 1 then /* change your check condition here */
        RaiseError("Do not send to subscriber", true)
    else
]%%
Hello!
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Result: it didn't send the PN to my device.

I also did check from Mobile Push Message detailed report and cannot find the message.

If I change the condition to `1==0` then I will receive the Hello message and the whole AMPscript will show in MessageContent column in the report.

Comment: Thanks @Duc Le for your sharing, looked like raise error is working for Push!

Comment: @KhoaNguyen it will abort the send in SMS also. Actually I was not aware about this in SMS and Push until you raised the question. So thanks to you too!